# src/ file path not found

Tags: java, src, ioexception, fileoutputstream

I want to save a serializable object into the src/ folder.

```
File file = new File("src/test.ser");
file.createNewFile();
fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
oos.writeObject(object);
```

However, `The system cannot find the path specified` error messege pops up. The method works if I use an absolute file path though.

If this is in any way relevant, I've added another project into the build path.

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: Print out the current directory location, and see if it is running where you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **./** before src.

```
File file = new File("./src/test.ser");
file.createNewFile();
fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
oos.writeObject(object);
```